# ServiceStack's Funq type registration via reflection?

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, funq

I've used Castle Windsor quite a bit.  It has a really handy facility for registering types via reflection.  So for example, I would do things like this at application startup:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IMyInterface>().LifestyleTransient());
```

So, say I had a bunch of providers for data formatting - I could register them all (via interface) with that one line.  Even better, when I created new ones (assuming they were in that same assembly, and same interface) they would then get registered as well; I wouldn't have to remember to do this when coding them.

Is there an equivalent in ServiceStack's implementation of the Funq container?  I've looked around, and don't seem to see one.

Answer (score 1):

An interface can only have a single implementation, but if you wanted to register all concrete types implementing an interface by scanning to find all types and pre-registering them with:

```
var fooTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.HasInterface(typeof(IFoo)));
container.RegisterAutoWiredTypes(fooTypes);
```

Which if needed can all be retrieved with:

```
 var fooInstances = fooTypes.Select(c.Resolve).Cast<IFoo>();
```

Which can also be registered as a dependency itself:

```
container.Register(c => fooTypes.Select(c.Resolve).Cast<IFoo>());
```

That your classes can access using property injection:

```
public IEnumerable<IFoo> FooInstances { get; set; }
```